# UPS for PC for repeat power cycling

Tags: power-supply

I am assembling a mobile test stand at work, which will be wheeled around from site-to-site within my building. It will contain data acquisition equipment, as well as a PC running software to handle the I/O and control various bits of hardware to automate common quality-control routines for the instruments on our test sites.

I would like the PC to be able to keep running as the cart is unplugged and moved around the building. Otherwise the PC has to be powered-down and re-booted every time the cart is moved.

Is it possible to use a UPS for this kind of use? My understanding is that they are not designed for repeated power cycling. In my use case, the cart would be unplugged for a max of 15 minutes, and would be plugged in on-site for at least 2 hours.

Comment: Just use a laptop? I don't know very many UPS that can go 15 minutes with only a 2 hour charge time

Comment: Use a laptop. An unplugged UPS is a safety hazard because it is no longer grounded yet can still output line voltage. Read the warnings of any UPS on this unsafe condition. Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/56999/testing-a-ups-by-unplugging-it-from-the-wall

Answer (score 1):

A laptop would seem like a good alternative, assuming your other data acquisition equipment doesn't need to stay powered on? But if it does, I would think most decent UPS's should be able to power your station for 15mins off/2hours on. I use one of these 
[http://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-SMART1500LCDT-1500VA-Battery/dp/B009TZTGWK/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1409772346&sr=8-9&keywords=ups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009TZTGWK) to power our server and it'll last over an hour unplugged. So that would be a minimum four 15 minute unplugged time frames it could handle, not including the 2 hour intervals it would be charging.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing to do is to buy a Kill-A-Watt or similar AC power meter and see how much power (watts) and volt-amps your cart uses. Then look at UPSs with compatible specs. Most UPSs are rated in terms of both volt-amps and watts. You mustn't exceed either rating. Plan on at least a 2x safety factor.

This however tells you only the maximum load, nothing about how long the UPS will run that load, or any other. But any reputable UPS manufacturer (Tripp-lite, APC) will include in their specs either a table or a graph that shows how long the UPS can be expected to run various loads. Plan on at least a 2x safety factor here too: If you really need 15 minutes, you want a UPS that can run your load for half an hour. This is to allow for both unexpected delays in getting back on wall power and for battery aging.

The more runtime you want for a given load, the larger, heavier, and pricier the UPS will be. It's common to say "most of it is in the battery" but high power battery charging circuits and inverters aren't small or lightweight either.

Recharge times... some mfrs will list recharge times. jAce had a great point: If your UPS can run your cart for much longer than required, then you don't necessarily need to recharge all the way to 100% between mobile ops. Another workaround: The better (more expensive) UPSs use easily replaceable hot-pluggable battery packs. So you buy two UPSs, and you start out with two battery packs. One UPS is used just as a recharger.

I'll have to pull a rundown/recharge test on my setup here... I have an older APC 1500VA "SmartUPS" and the system on it draws about 500 watts. Stay tuned. :)